# VS19 Xamarin deployment to Datalogic Skorpio X4 not possible. Error XA0132

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I have an app for scanning with the Skorpio X4 that has been running on it for over 2 months.
In the meantime I have updated Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.10.3. Now I wanted to test a new version of the application on the scanner. But whenever I want to debug on the scanner, I get the following error:

*XA0132: The package was not installed. Please check you do not have it installed under any other user.
If the package does show up on the device, try manually uninstalling it then try again.
You should be able to uninstall the app via the Settings app on the device.*

When I try to test the application on another device, it works.
You can't find much about this error on the Internet.
The only usefull link i found was this:
[Xamarin.Android error XA0132](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/guides/messages/xa0132.md).
I never changed user or something else as suggested here.

Does anyone have experience with this problem?

- Android-Version on Scanner: 4.4.4
- Datalogic SDK on Scanner: 1.21
- Visual Studio 2019: 16.10.3
- Android SKDs installed: API 19; API 28; API 30
- Windows 10 Build 19043.1110

**EDIT 1:**
I ran several cleanups, reinstalled all NuGet packages and did a factory reset of the scanner.

Comment: have you uninstalled all prior versions of the app from the device?  Have you checked the device logs for relevant messages?

Comment: yes. I factory reset of the scanner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution.
You have to untick the "Fast Deployment" box in the project settings.

Project Settings > Android-Options > Fast Deployment

This worked for me.